# Почему регулярки в онлайн проверке работают, а в жизни нет?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Подскажите, почему регулярка `#<li style="list-style-position:(.*?)>(.*?)<br/>#` [здесь](http://cp1251.darkoff.ru/regexp/) работает, а в коде нет ?

```
$x=file_get_contents('http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=90929&xhr=1');
 ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',10000000);
 $x=htmlspecialchars($x);

preg_match_all('#<li style="list-style-position:(.*?)>(.*?)<br/>#',$x,$matches);
echo $matches[2][1];
```

собственно код

Comment: В слэши регулярные выражения не обязательно загонять?) Плюс <br/> явно не встретится, т.к. $x обработан через htmlspecialchars().

Comment: Понял, какую ошибку совершил) Пойду переделывать)

Comment: После удаления  `$x=htmlspecialchars($x);` лучше не стало(

Comment: Я так понял, что потом всё-таки стало?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$x=file_get_contents('http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=90929&xhr=1');
 ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',10000000);
 // $x=htmlspecialchars($x);

preg_match_all('#<li style="list-style-position:(.*?)>(.*?)<br/>#',$x,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

а так?

Comment: Если `$matches[2][1]`, то выводит то, что нужно...
Xм... а что поменялось кроме `$x=htmlspecialchars($x);` никак не пойму.

Comment: Незнаю как, но оно начало работать....

Comment: хотя пробовал удалять эту строку

Comment: ну вот и славненько

Comment: в общем спасибо вам, светлый маг))