# Почему регулярки в онлайн проверке работают, а в жизни нет?#2

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36863/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82?rq=1&newreg=92aa500b091d438db80cb1fab7d26a3b), но не совсем
Пытаюсь вытащить цифру(Last trade price) из [страницы](http://quotes.morningstar.com/bondquote/quote?t=FAOVH4069694). Вроде как изи, но или я туплю или я туплю.... Вот мой код.

```
<?php
$url = "http://quotes.morningstar.com/bondq/quote/c-banner?
&t=FAOVH4069694";
$input_line=file_get_contents($url);
preg_match("/\$(.*?)\\n/", $input_line, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Выдает пустой массив.
А вот как на regexr работает: http://regexr.com/3gt62

Может туплю жестко, но спс за любой совет

Comment: Проверяйте на https://ru.functions-online.com/preg_match.html - там за вас напишут вызов функции. А так выходит `\n` экранировано неверно

Comment: Т.е. хотите найти первое число после знака `$`? Тогда `'/\$\K\d[\d.]*/'` подойдёт. Но лучше получить это значение через DOM.

Comment: В коде страницы нет цены/суммы. Только вызовы jquery со знаком `$` встречаются.

Comment: интересно, перевод каретки вы экранировали `\\n`, т.е. вы понимаете, что одинарные обратные косые надо удваивать, так как в двойных кавычках они становятся одной обратной косой... Так почему же вы этого не сделали перед знаком `$`. он у вас остается не экранированным и означает конец строки...

Comment: Ответ Mike действительно помог, Спасибо. Экранирую больше по привычке чем осмысленно)

Comment: @Mike, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> интересно, перевод каретки вы экранировали \n, т.е. вы понимаете, что одинарные обратные косые надо удваивать, так как в двойных кавычках они становятся одной обратной косой... Так почему же вы этого не сделали перед знаком $. он у вас остается не экранированным и означает конец строки...

(c) Mike